# How to read this local json file, and get the coordinates rendering on map with Markers on Adroid?

Tags: json, google-maps, react-native, google-maps-markers, street-address

My problem is to read the local json file and fetch the coordinates, here is some code to import the file:

`const data = require('./3ª Légua-Oriental-Nossa Senhora das Graças.json');`

And I need to fecht it to this parameters coordinate markers by id search, and show it to my map:

```
{data.map(
  (coordinates, index, title) => (
    <MapView.Marker
      key={`coordinate_${index}`}
      title={'Ponto'}
      coordinate={{
        latitude: coordinates.latitude,
        longitude: coordinates.longitude,
      }}>
    </MapView.Marker>
  )
)}
```

here is the json.file code for example:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "latitude": "-29.271225",
        "longitude": "-51.1895903",
        "horario de inicio": "05:55:00"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "latitude": "-29.2511256",
        "longitude": "-51.1932803",
        "horario de inicio": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "latitude": "-29.2434067",
        "longitude": "-51.1985995",
        "horario de inicio": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "latitude": "-29.2358186",
        "longitude": "-51.1889452",
        "horario de inicio": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "latitude": "-29.2315023",
        "longitude": "-51.1893468",
        "horario de inicio": ""
    }
]
```

[image]

Comment: here is the snack: https://snack.expo.io/@matheus_cbrl/tinpet

Comment: Your code looks fine, what is the problem? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: if you run the snack above, you will see that have no one marker rendered in the map... I want to show the markers in the archive json...

Comment: I can see the markers on IOS, it works.

Comment: Can you help me to work in the android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for this problem here is the modifications:

this:

```
 {data.map(
      (coordinates, index, title) => (
        <MapView.Marker
          key={`coordinate_${index}`}
          title={'Ponto'}
          coordinate={{
            latitude: coordinates.latitude,
            longitude: coordinates.longitude,
          }}>
        </MapView.Marker>
      )
  )}
```

to :

```
{locations.map(
        (locations, id, latitude, longitude, hora) => (
          console.log(locations.latitude, locations.latitude),
          (
            <MapView.Marker
              onPress={this.handleMapPress}
              ref={mark => (locations.mark = mark)}
              key={id}
              title={'Parada'}
              description={locations.hora}
              coordinate={{
                latitude: JSON.parse(locations.latitude),
                longitude: JSON.parse(locations.longitude),
              }}>
              <Image
                onPress={e => this.onPressMarker(e, id)}
                source={
                  this.state.selectedMarkerIndex === id
                    ? placholder2
                    : placholder
                }
                style={styles.icon}
              />
            </MapView.Marker>
          )
        )
      )}
```

The  code :`JSON.parse(reference.latitude),` make possible to read the coordinates from a local json file.
here below is the follow entire code in a snack example feel free to use this code, possible will save some lives.. hehehe

here is the link: [Map marker with a json coordinates](https://snack.expo.io/@matheus_cbrl/render-marker-from-a-local-json-file-coordinates)
the follow code have a bonus, it is possible take the address from a PinMarker in the map, with animation icon change...